# Do I need to Subclass from NSObject?

Tags: objective-c

I'm starting Objective-C Development and I'm trying to wrap my head around how some things work.

I'm creating a Twitter Client and have a class "Tweet". This is just a DTO - a class that has some variables.

Should this just be a class or should it inherit from NSObject?

Why? Or why not?

Comment: Same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588281/why-subclass-nsobject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every normal class should subclass from NSObject. Basic memory management like `-retain` and `-release`, and runtime introspection like `-isKindOfClass:`, `-respondsToSelector:` cannot work without it.

Comment: Absolutely, every class should have either NSObject or NSProxy as its root object unless you really want to do tons of extra work and suffer a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

You should, unless you have a very explicit, strong reason not to. In Objective-C, any object can be assigned to an `id`. But `id` doesn't guarantee any methods at all, even the standard operations such as allocation, initialization, deallocation and reference counting.

These are implemented by a root class, which is almost always an `NSObject`.

Also, most of the Cocoa API expects to deal with an `NSObject`, because it needs to at least `retain` and `release` the object.

So you should inherit from `NSObject`.