# About Delegate in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

```
@protocol MyButtonViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)buttonView:(MyButtonView*)view buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button;
@end
```

i am new in objective-c, i am learning `delegate` according the book.

from the book, when we define protocol we just write like this `@protocol MyButtonViewDelegate`.

But what's the difference beteween `@protocol MyButtonViewDelegate` and `@protocol MyButtonViewDelegate <NSObject>`. Why we need `<NSObject>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588281/why-subclass-nsobject

Comment: @Paddyd The question you linked is quite different from this one. The linked question asks why (mostly) all objects are derived from NSObject, whereas this one asks why a protocol would adopt the NSObject protocol and whether that's necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But what's the difference beteween `@protocol MyButtonViewDelegate`
>   and `@protocol MyButtonViewDelegate <NSObject>`.

The `<NSObject>` says that the protocol `MyButtonViewDelegate` conforms to [the `NSObject` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html). That is, any object that conforms to the `MyButtonViewDelegate` protocol must also conform to the `NSObject` protocol. (You may not have realized it, but there's a protocol named `NSObject` as well as a class by that same name.) So, if you've got an object that conforms to `MyButtonViewDelegate`, it's safe to call methods like `-hash`, `-isEqual:`, `-retain`, `-release`, `-isKindOfClass:`, etc.

Every object you're likely to encounter will already conform to `NSObject` because the class `NSObject` conforms to protocol `NSObject`. The only other Objective-C base class that you might run into is `NSProxy`, and that also conforms to `NSObject`. Therefore, adding `<NSObject>` to your protocol probably won't make a real difference, but it's a nice way to make the requirement explicit.

Comment: I got it. protocol `MyButtonViewDelegate` inherit protocol `NSObject`. I just think `NSObject` is a class, but i am wrong, it is also a protocol.

Comment: @BlackMamba There's a class *and* a protocol named `NSObject`. The protocol declares a set of methods that every object, even those not derived from the `NSObject` class, is expected to implement.