# Consequences of not using NSObject as a superclass?

Tags: superclass, nsobject

What are the consequences of not declaring inheritance from NSObject?

I know this has been answered, kinda, in other answers such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588281/why-subclass-nsobject) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295317/what-use-cases-are-there-for-defining-a-new-root-class?lq=1) etc etc.

But none of the answers really go into the consequences of not inheriting from NSObject.

So specifically, if I do not subclass from NSObject for a critical class in my app, will I find out later on that this introduces a fundamental flaw into my app? Assume for whatever reason I would not be able to just subclass from NSObject later on.

thanks

Comment: It will also mean you'll have to implement all NSObject's methods (e.g: alloc), at least the one listed in the NSObject protocol (e.g: retain/release). What would be the benefit for you?

Comment: @Macmade, memory. I know NSObject isn't that big but every bit, nibble and byte is going to count in what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Lots of methods does not mean a lot of memory per instance... Actually, the size of an NSObject instance is 16 bytes...